# Patchvalue in angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I my angular application, i am using angular dynamic form in which i am patching value with some json.

```
  data =
  {
    firstName:"Eliseo",
    lastName:"Plunker",
    myArray:
    [
    {
    emailAddress:"eliseo@plunker.com",
    brave:"solid"
    },
    {
    emailAddress:"eliseo@plunker.org",
    brave:"great"
    }
    ]
  }
```

Patchvalue function:

```
  fillData()
  {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
    for (let i=0;i<this.data.myArray.length;i++)
    {
      this.addControls('myArray');
    }
    //Use patchValue
    this.form.patchValue(this.data);

  }
```

Here in this function, i want to patch only the `myArray` values and not the `firstName` and `lastName`.

I have tried with **this.data.myArray**

```
    this.form.patchValue(this.data.myArray);
```

But it doesn't work.

The **working stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-wztvq9

Click over **Fill Form** button in the above demo to get the patched values in the form..

Kindly help me to patch only the `myArray` value and leave others empty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to patch myArray values

```
this.form.patchValue({
  'myArray' : this.data.myArray
});
```

Hope this helps!!